# SQL: add logic to handle tie when select max value

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table like this:

| store | shelf | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | s1 | t1 | 3 |
| A | s1 | t2 | 4 |
| A | s2 | t3 | 2 |
| A | s2 | t2 | 2 |
| A | s3 | t4 | 1 |
| A | s3 | t5 | 1 |

I want to know the dominant type per store per shelf. The rule is:

for each store and shelf:

1. if there's a max value of count for one type, the dominant would be this type.
   for store A shelf s1, it would be t2, because t2 > t1)
2. if there's tie, then check the count of the type for store total, and use whichever has a larger store total.
   for store A shelf s2, it would be t2, because total count of t2 (2 + 4) > total count of t3 (2)
3. if still a tie, will put dominant as "can't decide".
   for store A shelf s3, it would be "can't decide"

Sample output:

| store | shelf | dominantType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | s1 | t2 |
| A | s2 | t2 |
| A | s3 | can't decide |

Now I can achieve the first 2 rules with first calculating `countStoreLevel`, then use ROW_NUMBER() OVER:

```
rank AS (
SELECT table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store, shelf ORDER BY count DESC, countStoreLevel DESC) AS rn
FROM shopping)

SELECT * FROM rank WHERE rn = 1
```

But I don't know how to deal with rule 3, when there's a tie, and it should be can't decide.

Could anyone help me with it? Thanks a looooot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  The idea is:

- Count up the rows with `type` by shelf and by store.
- Enumerate the counts within a shelf and within a store by the count, so you know which count is highest.
- Check if there is only one type for a shelf.  If so, use that.
- Check if there is only one type for a store.  If so, use that.
- Otherwise, `'can''t decide'`.

As a query, this looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(case when seqnum_shelf = 1 then type end) over (partition by store, shelf) =
                  max(case when seqnum_shelf = 1 then type end) over (partition by store, shelf) =
             then min(case when seqnum_shelf = 1 then type end) over (partition by store, shelf)
             when min(case when seqnum_store = 1 then type end) over (partition by store) =
                  max(case when seqnum_store = 1 then type end) over (partition by store) =
             then min(case when seqnum_store = 1 then type end) over (partition by store)
             else 'can''t decide'
          end) as dominantType                   
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by store, shelf order by cnt_shelf desc) as seqnum_shelf,
             dense_rank() over (partition by store order by cnt_shelf desc) as seqnum_store
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by store, shelf, type) as cnt_shelf,
                   count(*) over (partition by store, type) as cnt_store
            from t
        ) t;
```